# How can I run the Blender desktop app (blender.org) in the cloud?

Tags: cloud, virtualization, blender

I would like several people to be able to access  Blender on a server, and work with it.

What is the best way to do this?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I use dropbox. I uploaded a blender release and put in a subfolder all my .blend files, shared with my teammates. It works till we don't want to edit the same file at the same time... unfortunately blender doesn't support co-operative work.

This method should work on all desktop operation system.